# Regular expression for text extraction

Tags: javascript, regex

Can you please help me with the regular expression. I am newbie to this.

my requirement is I want to extract the vehicle no (i.e, 123456789) from the below url :

```
mysite.com/resource?slk=121&ops=rewww&from=kld&to=aop&search=things&validVehicle=sdfdsdff-sdfdf-sddf%3AVX%3ALNCX%3A123456789%3AOPW%3ALOS
```

I tried the below expression:

```
[&?]{1}validVehicle[=]{1}[^&]*[%3A]{1}([^%&]+)
```

But it is giving invalid results. Can you pelase help me on this.

Comment: what programming language do you use?

Comment: Perhaps, [`[&?]validVehicle=[^&]*%3A(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/TjfhX5/2) will do the job. Or [`[&?]validVehicle=[^&]*(\d{9})`](https://regex101.com/r/TjfhX5/3). What are the requirements for the vehicle number?

Comment: yes it does https://regex101.com/r/JqDSBG/1

Comment: Can you provide some more context? What language/framework? There may be a much simpler + more reliable solution than a direct regex on the HTTP parameter.

Comment: maybe this also can help you [\d{9}](https://regex101.com/r/TjfhX5/4) if you know the real length of the vehicle no

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thanks for reply...vehicleNumber is 9 digit number...

Comment: Hi Tom, this one is limited to regex, I am doing validation with the JS

Comment: In sublime text:

^.*validVehicle(.*?%3A){3}(\d*)

Searches for the first occurence of 'validVehicle' and then goes three '%3A' divider forwards and then capture the number in capture group 2 accessed by (\2)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Wikto & fxlacroix for the comments...

Answer (score 1):

A pure regex solution:

```
[&?]validVehicle=[^&]*(\d{9})
```

Or, if you are sure they appear after `%3A` and not followed with a digit:

```
[&?]validVehicle=[^&]*%3A(\d{9})(?!\d)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TjfhX5/3) and [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HKrka5/1). The value you seek is in Group 1.

**Details**:

- `[&?]` - a `?` or `&`
- `validVehicle=` - a literal substring
- `[^&]*` - any symbols other than `&`, as many as possible up to the last
- `%3A` - literal substring
- `(\d{9})` - Group 1: 9 digits
- `(?!\d)` - not followed with a digit.

Answer (score 0):

A "structural" [approach](https://regex101.com/r/TjfhX5/6) might be to use those "%3a" colons as the delimiters of the pattern, combined with non-greedy wildcards `.*` (this matches *fourth* field of 'validVehicle' as defined by the delimiter `%3a`, and assumes this structure does not change):

```
[&?]validVehicle=(?:.*?%3a){3}(.*?)%3a
```

The utility of this way vs the `\d{9}` patterns already suggested really just depends on what you know for certain about the incoming data.  Such patterns would certainly match nine digits in *other* fields of that delimited value.